# Spark tasks execution series

Tags: apache-spark

I am running a Spark application on the driver.

Is is simple as follow

```
val count=0; 
val test_dataframe =//extrenal frame
count=test.count();
println("The count of frame is " + count);
```

My question is that if the third line is always executed after computing the count of frame. Is it possible the driver first run the `println` command, before executing the dataframe and its count?

Comment: how will you print the count without performing count operation on dataframe?

Comment: The count is initially declared as zero.

Comment: I saw that. However that didn't make any sense to me to print just zero. What if you put that println statement before `count=test.count()` this line?

Comment: my question is that possible println run without processing datafraem and then printing 0?

Comment: I asssume that instead of `test.count` you meant `test_dataframe.count`. As your declared dataframe name is  `test_dataframe` and not `test`.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible that driver will execute println before `test.count()` in above mentioned code as count is a tearminal operation and call to a terminal operation forces spark to perform computation before moving on.

If you want async count then here is a code snippet which works:

```
var future = test.rdd.countAsync
println("The count before future evaluation: " + count)
count = future.get
println("The count after future evaluation: " + count)
```

Note that countAsync action is not available directly on dataframe. It can be performed on RDD.

Comment: I feel not, "test.count" would be an Asynchronous operation in the nature!

Comment: count is a synchronous action by default. There are several async actions supported by spark. If you want asyc behaviour then you need to explicitly mention that in your code.check this class: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/rdd/AsyncRDDActions.html

Comment: @Luckylukee does above explanation clears your doubt? Also I have updated the answer with a code snippet for async count.